# Customize Button And Success Message In Active Admin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to customize following things

1. Actions Name like "Add User" => "Create User", "Edit User" => "Update User" etc
2. Success Message On Delete, Create and Edit like "user successfully created" => "customer successfully created"
3. Add A Create Button On Show Page beside edit and delete

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

> Actions Name like "Add User" => "Create User", "Edit User" => "Update
>   User" etc

Instead of having `f.actions`, you could have

```
<%= f.actions do %>
  <%= f.action :submit, as: :button, label: 'Create User' %>
  <%= f.action :cancel, as: :link %> # change it to button if needed
<% end %>
```

ActiveAdmin uses formtastic, [**read more here**](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic).

> Success Message On Delete, Create and Edit like "user successfully
>   created" => "customer successfully created"

```
def create # or any other action
  super do |format| # this is important - override the original implementation
    redirect_to(
      admin_users_path,
      notice: 'Your custom message for successful user creation'
    ) and return
  end
end
```

You could also try this:

```
def create # or any other action
  super do |format| # this is important - override the original implementation
    flash[:notice] = 'Your custom message for successful user creation'
    # you do understand, that if you have different routes you should change this, right?
    redirect_to admin_users_path
  end
end
```

> Add A Create Button On Show Page beside edit and delete

```
  action_item only: :show  do
    link_to 'Create new user', new_admin_users_path
  end
```

Comment: 1 and 2 not working ......

In first, Cancel showing as link

In Second, Nothing Happening

Comment: I edited the answer, 1st - read documentation as I suggested and [gave you the link](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#the-story). 2 it should work, did you define it inside `controller do end` block?

Answer (score 4):

I am adding answer for second(refrence from above), But On validation errors above is not working so i customize it which can help you better

```
   controller do

    def update 
      super do |format| 
        if !@your_object.errors.any?
          redirect_to(
            admin_my_localities_path,
            notice: 'custom message.'
          ) and return
        end
      end
    end


    def destroy 
      super do |format| 
        if !@your_object.errors.any?
          redirect_to(
            admin_my_localities_path,
            notice: 'custom message.'
          ) and return
        else
          redirect_to(
            admin_my_localities_path,
            alert: 'custom error.'
          ) and return
        end
      end
    end
end
```